# xamarin android - select all edittext on double tap

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to select all text when double tapping on an EditText (not on the text itself but on the white space outside the text) by creating a GestureDetector and listener and in onDoubleTap perform the selecteAll. 
Unfortunately, just after all text gets selected, the text gets de-selected.

How can I select all text when double tap on the EditText white space?
Thanks!

Custom EditText:

```
public class TextEditText : EditText, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public TextEditText(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Init();
        }

        public TextEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base(context, attrs)
        {
            Init();
        }

        public TextEditText(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
            base(context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Init();
        }

        public TextEditText(IntPtr a, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership b) : base(a, b)
        {
            Init();
        }

        void Init()
        {
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SelectTextDoubleTapListener(this));
            SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            return gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
```

then the listener:

```
public class SelectTextDoubleTapListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        EditText editText;

        public SelectTextDoubleTapListener(EditText et)
        {
            editText = et;
        }

        public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (editText.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                editText.SetSelection(editText.Text.Length);
                editText.SelectAll();
            }

            return false; // return true does not work either
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, just after all text gets selected, the text gets de-selected.

I solve this by use `SetSelectAllOnFocus(true)` in the `OnDoubleTap`

For example:

```
    public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
    {            
        if (editText.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            editText.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            editText.ClearFocus();
        }            
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: Not working in my case; the text already has SetSelectAllOnFocus(true); which was added for normal selection/single tap/focus enter. The result is the same: just after the whole text gets selected, it gets de-selected as if I would have tapped the third time.

Comment: Do you want to de-selected the text only by double click or not de-selected when it is selected?

Comment: I want to select all text when double tapping on the whitespace of the edittext (not the text/string itself).

Comment: Here is the result of my code : [Gif](https://imgur.com/a/sZQxF) . And what do you want when you tapped the third time?